# Django inheriting from multiple model classes

Tags: django

So I have a base abstract model class

```
class AbstractBase(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField()
    // Some fields

   class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

Now many classes inherit from this Base. Each category has its own fields

```
class Category1(AbstractBase):
      //some code



class Category2(AbstractBase):
          //some code
```

.
   .
   .

```
class CategoryN(AbstractBase):
          //some code
```

Now I do not wish to create separate inlines etc for each of these models.

This is because in the admin only one of these models need to be displayed depending on which category it is.

```
class CategoryAdminInLine(nested.NestedTabularInline):
     model = Category
     fields = //some common fields
```

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the package django-polymorphic https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic
It adds transparent admin and QuerySet integration for inherited models.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to simply remove the abstract=True from the base class.
However, I'm afraid this may not be the right way to do it as it may be copying and duplicating the tables and stuff but works great if the tables won't get too big!..

According to how it's done here.. https://godjango.com/blog/django-abstract-base-class-multi-table-inheritance/